# Google App Engine PHP servir archivos en subcarpeta (yaml)

Tags: php, configuración, deployment, google-app-engine, gcloud

Estoy intentando hacer funcionar una aplicación php en google app engine y solo puedo hacer que cargue el index.php.

La aplicación tiene el index.php en la raiz y luego los demas archivos php se encuentran dentro de la carpeta '/sistema'.

Este es el yaml que tengo hasta ahora:

```
handlers:
- url: /sistema/css/*
  static_dir: sistema/css
- url: /sistema/js/*
  static_dir: sistema/js
- url: /sistema/fonts/*
  static_dir: sistema/fonts
- url: /sistema/images/*
  static_dir: sistema/images
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /sistema/*
  script: \1
- url: /
  script: index.php
```

Carga sólo el index.php pero luego no puedo hacer que funcionen las demás paginas dentro de la carpeta sistema.

**Como debería ser mi yaml?**

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

para que no se te haga el archivo app.yaml enorme configuralo de esta manera:
handlers:
/*Esto es para las extensiones de tu demas archivos no tegas problemas*/
- url: /(.+.(js|gif|png|jpg|json|css|jpeg|pdf|xls|xlsx))$
    static_files: \1
    upload: .+.(js|gif|png|jpg|json|css|jpeg|pdf|xls|xlsx)$
/*Con esto ya no colocas tantas lineas de estar repetiendo carpeta por carpeta*/
- url: .*
    script: auto
    secure: always
y en el index.php configura:
$pag_index = 'index.php';
    switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
          case @parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']:
                $url_path = substr(@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'],1);
                $url_path = empty($url_path)?$pag_index:$url_path;
                $url_path = ($url_path == 'index.php')?$pag_index:$url_path;
                require $url_path;
                break;
          default:
                break;
    }